# Determine if $n$ could be represented by a quadratic form of discriminant $d$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

So, I know this is only possible whenever $d$ is a square $\pmod{4\cdot |n|}$, but can that be simplified any further?

As an example, if I am given that $d=-39$ and $n=500$, this reduces to solving $x^2 \equiv -39 \pmod{500}$, but how can I find concrete $x$'s that satisfy the equation? What if the $x$'s have to be prime?

Comment: Solving $x^2 \equiv d  \mod n$ is the [modular square root problem](https://www.rieselprime.de/ziki/Modular_square_root).  It is hard in general, but there are algorithms for it.   Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions tells you there will always be primes $\equiv x \mod n$.for any $x$ coprime to $n$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Is there any good way of going about it other than just brute-forcing it?

Comment: ... of going about which "it"?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Of solving the modular root problem.

Comment: Did you look at the link?  Or try [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Complexity_of_finding_square_roots).

Comment: @RobertIsrael It gives a series of cases (if the modulus is congruent to $3 \pmod 4$, etc.). In my case, I have $1000=2^3 \cdot 5^3$, but $2^3=8$ is divisible by both $4$ and $8$, which is not listed among the cases. Does this imply there is no solution?

Comment: To solve $x^2 \equiv d \mod 1000$, solve mod $2^3$ and mod $5^3$ and use Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Mod $8$ is easy: $x^2 \equiv 0 \mod 8$ if $x$ is divisible by $4$, $1$ if $x$ is odd, $4$ if $x$ is even but not divisible by $4$.  Mod $125$: first solve mod $5$, then Hensel lifting (if $d$ is not divisible by $5$).

Comment: jib, you and another are asking about discriminant $-39.$ What is the exact source of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's do the example $x^2 \equiv -39 \mod 500$.  $500 = 4 \times 5^3 $ so we'll solve it mod $4$ and mod $5^3$, and use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

$-39 \equiv 1 \mod 4$, and $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 4$ iff $x$ is odd, i.e. $x \equiv 1$ or $3 \mod 4$.

$-39 \equiv 1 \mod 5$, and $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 5$ iff $x \equiv 1$ or $4 \mod 5$.

If $x = 1 + 5 y$, $x^2 \equiv 1 + 10 y \equiv -39 \mod 25$ iff $2 y \equiv 3 \mod 5$ iff $y \equiv 1 \mod 5$.
If $x = 1 + 5 \cdot 1 + 5^2 \cdot z = 6 + 5^2 \cdot z$,
$x^2 \equiv 6^2 + 2 \cdot 6 \cdot 5^2 z \equiv 36 + 50 z \equiv -39 \mod 125$ iff $50 z \equiv 50 \mod 125$ iff $z \equiv 1 \mod 5$.  Thus $x \equiv 1 + 5 \cdot 1 + 5^2 \cdot 1 = 31\mod 125$.

Similarly, corresponding to $x \equiv 4 \equiv -1 \mod 5$ we find $x \equiv -31 \equiv 94 \mod 125$.

Now for Chinese Remainder.  There are $4$ cases to consider:

1. If $x \equiv 1 \mod 4$ and $x \equiv 31 \mod 125$, $x \equiv 281 \mod 500$.
2. If $x \equiv 1 \mod 4$ and $x \equiv 94 \mod 125$, $x \equiv 469 \mod 500$.
3. If $x \equiv 3 \mod 4$ and $x \equiv 31 \mod 125$, $x \equiv 31 \mod 500$.
4. If $x \equiv 3 \mod 4$ and $x \equiv 94 \mod 125$, $x \equiv 219 \mod 500$.

So the solutions mod $500$ are $281, 469, 31$ and $219$.

Each of these four values mod $500$ should correspond to infinitely many primes.  The simplest thing to do is to check $281 + 500 k$, $461 + 500 k$, $31 + 500 k$, $219 + 500 k$ for each integer $k$ from $0$ until we find as many primes as we want.  As it happens, all but $219$ turn out to be prime for $k=0$, while $219 + 500 = 719$ is prime.

Comment: Robert, there are two people asking about discriminant $-39$ this morning. The other one wants to find all reduced binary forms

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3775931/reduced-quadratic-forms-with-discriminant-39