# Reduced quadratic forms with discriminant -39

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

How would I find all reduced forms with discriminant -39? I tried setting it up:

$d = b^2-4ac = -39$ and was able to see that, for example, $1^2-4(2)(5)$ would work (since $-2 \leq 1 \leq 2 < 5$), but is there any way to find the other $a$'s, $b$'s, and $c$'s that would work?

Edit: We can bound $|a|$ by $\sqrt{\frac{-d}{3}}$. Is it just a case of checking all the combinations that work after that?

Comment: there are explicit bounds, and it really is a matter of checking all combinations. Note $b$ is odd, reduced begins with $|b| \leq a \leq c $ and there is a little more to check

Comment: as $39$ is a product of two distinct primes, we get two genera. In turn, this requires two ambiguous forms. Ambiguous (reduced positive) forms are types $\langle a,0,c \rangle,$ not relevant here, also $\langle a,a,c \rangle,$  and $\langle a,b,a \rangle,$